# How to read SQL Server CE SDF file in Linux Platform

Tags: linux, sql-server-ce

I want to extract some data from a `.SDF` file where the server operates on Linux platform. There is no database access to the SQL Server CE database which is present on a remote server.

I want to achieve the task by using PERL but can use C or any language if required.

Answer (score 0):

You can only open SQL Server Compact SDF files on Windows, you could expose the data to a Unix machine via a REST API or similar.

Comment: Thanks Erik. I was trying the same using freetds/Linux. But now I am going to develop an agent for Windows which can read the SDF file.